# How to change message for validation constraint in Symfony globally?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-validator

Is there a way to change the basic validation error message to one I need for all entities at once? Currently using **Yaml** config for every entity, but it's not a way.

```yaml
CF\MyBundle\Entity\User:
  properties:
    email:
      - Email:
          message: e-mail no válido
      - NotBlank:
          message: Campo obligatorio
    username:
      - NotBlank:
          message: Campo obligatorio
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to define an translations file.

```
# app/Resources/translations/validators.es.yml
This value should not be blank.: Campo obligatorio
This value is not a valid email address.: e-mail no válido
```